# Why does Munkres say "we shall seldom have occasion to use the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$"?

Tags: metric-spaces, soft-question

I'm not sure if opinion-based questions like this are appropriate here, but I'm a bit confused by something I read in Munkres in the section on the metric topology. Specifically, in the first edition on page 120, near where the Euclidean and square metrics are defined, it reads

> "The proof that $d$ is a metric requires some work; it is probably already familiar to you. If not, a proof is outlined in the exercises. We shall seldom have occasion to use the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$."

It's this last sentence which is confusing to me. Surely the author doesn't mean in general, perhaps just in this book? You could argue that anytime they do anything with the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$, we're using the Euclidean metric.

Comment: Yes, he means in this book. It will usually be about general topological spaces without a given metric.

Comment: He does mean "in this book". Perhaps because topologically it's much simpler to characterize $\Bbb R^n$ as a product space than as a metric space?

Comment: As **MJD** says, for purely topological purposes it is much simpler to think of $\Bbb R^n$ as a product. And there are metrics on it that generate the product topology and are easier to work with than the Euclidean metric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely yes, it is not a general answer and the domain is the book itself. Munkres’ book is all about general topology (hence more general than a metric space) and algebraic topology, so it is not interested in the metric structure, that is more the topic of analysis or geometric analysis (differential geometry). In Real Analysis, when one generalizes the structure of the real numbers to a general metric space, the notion of distance (and the Euclidean is a particular one) is fundamental.

As regards the study of shapes and geometry overall, topology is the study of properties that are stable via homeomorphisms, regardless the metric structure. On the other hand, on more advanced topological spaces one wants to study functions that preserve the metric structure of the topological space (endowed with a particular metric) and so you jump into the field of differential geometry, Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis, that are a nice intersection of topology and analysis.

Comment: It's also worth keeping in mind that even if we do want to metrize the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$, there are metrics simpler than the Euclidean metric which do the job, such as the [taxicab metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean metric and $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the taxicab metric are homeomorphic, but not isometric, metric spaces; if we only care about things "up to homeomorphism" (or equivalently only care about "homeomorphism-invariant" properties), there's no reason to prefer one to the other.

Comment: Exactly, totally agree!